# Fhir appointment resource additional data elements

Tags: resources, hl7-fhir, appointment

I have a situation that about 15 more additional data elements need to add which is not part of appointment resource. What are the options I have ? Can I use extensions to add additional elements ? If so do I need separate extensions for these 15 elements? Can someone please suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what the elements are.  It's possible they belong in a resource other than the Appointment - e.g. Patient, Practitioner, Slot, Schedule.  If so, these can be conveyed in the referenced resource, or in some cases, as a 'contained' resource.

It might be the information can fit in one of the standard elements.  It might be there's already a standard core or IG-defined extension for what you're trying to do.  Or it may be necessary for you to define your own extension.

The best thing to do when faced with elements you don't know how to map is to ask a question on http://chat.fhir.org.  However, don't just name the elements (as that's often not enough to understand what they do/what they're for).  Also provide definitions and/or example values.  The broader community can then give you guidance on how best to share them in a way that will maximize consistency with other implementations.